# How do I update an int variable using my getline(s, lc) function without using "pointers"? (C)

Tags: c, string, variables, int, procedure

I am doing exercise 2-5 in K&R C and I decided to implement a function called `getline(s, lc)` where `s` is the string to concatenate the characters with and `lc` is an integer to count lines.

You guys might say that this is a possible duplicate but I am going to first explain how this question is different.

1. **[Update (int) variable in C inside a function [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667497/update-int-variable-in-c-inside-a-function)** - This involves pointers but I am asking how I can update a variable without using pointers. I am a "n00b" at it.
2. **[How to change variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377158/how-to-change-variable)** - This also involves pointers and doesn't have an accepted answer.

I want the program to run like this: (Overall)

```
String 0: the big brown fox jumped over lazy dog
String 1: lazy

First Occurrence: 29
```

I want my program to work that way in overall; Ask a user to input two string and if one character in `String 1:` matches in `String 0:` it will return the first occurrence of that character.

But let's focus on the first part where I implemented `getline(s, lc)`. Putting a character in string is possible but I want to know if it's possible updating an integer variable.

As of now, this is how my program runs:

```
String 0: DEEP BLUE SKY
String 0: BLUE CAKE
```

The prompt where `BLUE CAKE` is should be `String 1:` not `String 0:` again.

```
/* getline: gets the character input and convert it into a string. */
void getline(char s[], int lc)
{
    int c, i, lim;

    lim = LIMIT;
    i = 0;

    printf("String %d: ", lc);
    while (lim > 0) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == '\n' || c == EOF) {
            lim = 0;
        }
        else {
            s[i] = c;
            ++i;
       }
    }
    ++lc;
    s[i] = '\0';
}
```

[And here's the link.](http://pastebin.com/aL44W1XW)

Is there a way to update an integer variable `lc` by `1` using a function without using pointers?

I want to solve this problem using what I learned so far in the book keeping away advanced topics.

Comment: One option is to have `getline` return the updated value of `lc` and then use `lc = getline(s, lc);`

Comment: But will the strings still be updated after executing this function?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Nevermind, I tested it and it worked. I would +1 your first post but I need more reputation.

Comment: why don't you put lc increasement inside your main() method?

Comment: @Robin I want the `getline(s, lc)` function to update the variables for me, not the `main()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can by making the function return the value

```
int getline(char s[], int lc)
{
  ...

  return ++lc;
}
```

The string is passed by reference to the function so any changes you do to the string will anyway be visible outside the function. In effect char s[] passes the address where the string resides so you are free to change its contents inside your getline function.

The problem with your getline function is that it does not know the max size of the array since there is no such information available in the array itself. You should add the size as an argument as well to avoid memory overwrites.

e.g.

```
int getline(char s[], int maxlen, int lc)
```

Comment: I accepted your answer since not only you gave a solution, you also helped me about the limit of a character array.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the function return the integer as its return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can either return `lc` from your function or use `lc` as a global variable  (better to avoid using global variable).